# Что значат операторы @ и ^ в Делфи?

Tags: delphi, указатели

Что значат операторы **@** и **^** ?? Так же хочется узнать, что будет в **Pkts** если Psh[4, 1] = ?

```
Blocks = 4; 
RTParts = 2; 
BlNum, ROTO: integer
mkts = array [0..3, 1..6, 1..16] of SmallInt;
msh = array[1..392] of SmallInt;
TPmkts = ^mkts;
TPmsh = ^msh;
Pkts: array[1..Blocks, 1..RTParts] of TPmkts = ( (nil, nil), (nil, nil), (nil, nil), (nil, nil) );
Psh: array[1..Blocks, 1..RTParts] of TPmsh = ( (nil, nil), (nil, nil), (nil, nil), (nil, nil) );

Pkts[Num, ROTO]:= @Psh[Num, ROTO]^[9];
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос объявление переменных `Pkts` и `Psh`. Судя по всему они многомерные массивы

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Оператор `@` обозначает взятие адреса переменной (получение указателя на переменную)

Оператор `^` в коде обозначает разыменование указателя и получение значения переменной.

Оператор `^` при объявлении типа обозначает использование указателя. Например `PPoint = ^TPoint` обозначает, что объект типа `PPoint` будет указателем на объект типа `TPoint`.

Эти операторы дополняют друг друга.

```
var
  a: integer;
  b: pointer;
begin
  a := 123;

  // теперь b указывает на a
  b := @a; 

  // приводим указатель к конкретному типу и записываем в адрес,
  // на который указывает b - новое значение 120
  // теперь a будет 120
  PInteger(b)^ := 120; 
end;
```

---

> что будет в Pkts если Psh[4, 1] = 230 ?
>
> ```
> Pkts[4, 1]:= @Psh[4, 1]^[9];
> ```

В `Pkts[4,1]` будет элемент со смещением 9 от `Psh[4,1]`.

Давайте разберем по шагам, мы получаем адрес переменной Psh[4,1], тут же его разыменовываем обратно в переменную, и от этой переменной берем `[9]` элемент (то есть похоже что это строка или другой массив).

Обратите внимание, что подобный код не скомпилируется в Делфи, т.к. не указан разыменуемый тип `@Psh[4, 1]`.

Comment: Смысл указателя понятен, но не могу понять result= Psh^[9]; если psh = 230 ? Что будет тогда в result ? Спасибо большое.

Comment: Код подправил к тому , как он выглядит.

Comment: Это уже отладка кода. Думаю вам будет проще самостоятельно протестировать что там окажется.

Comment: А смещение куда выполняется ? вправо или влево ?

Comment: @creamsun вперед естественно.

Comment: @creamsun указатель не может быть равен 230, это слишком маленький адрес

Comment: @Kromster а как будет происходить смещение если вместо [9] будет [0,3,1] ?

Comment: @creamsun скорее всего никак, т.к. не совпадут типы. Для обращения к 9 элементу он должен существовать. Для обращения к 1 элементу массива из 3-го элемента массива из 0-го элемента массива - они все должны существовать и быть доступны.

Comment: @Kromster значит, это смещение в 3х мерном массиве ?

Comment: @creamsun это несколько разные понятия. Смещение происходит в одномерном массиве - в памяти. Обращение к элементу массива(ов) происходит согласно структуре расположения элемента в массивах. Как конкретно реализована структура расположения массивов в памяти я сейчас не вспомню. Надо проверять. Возможно вам стоит подготовить http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve и задать конкретный вопрос по вашей проблеме.

Comment: @Kromster хорошо, спасибо.